# Use special characters MySQL python

Tags: python, mysql, database, string, utf

I am doing a database and i want to insert a string in a row name VARCHAR[50]. 
I am getting the error: `mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 1366 (HY000): Incorrect string value: '\xC5\x88ol H...' for column 'name' at row 187`

some strings have special characters like "François", "L'adore", "Décade","France!". How can i insert this strings?

my query to insert is: `sql = "INSERT INTO Channels (name,sid,encrypted, freq,sat_id) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
mycursor.executemany(sql, data)` and the first value of data is `str(ch[a])`.

the string in row 187 is `CGTN Français HD`, it gives me error because dont accept "ç" char, how can i make mysql accept that kind of chars?

Comment: No idea without seeing _how_ you're trying to do the insert. I'm guessing string formatting.

Comment: i already edited to be more clear

Comment: Make sure your column has the correct character set I believe 'utf-8' should sufice

Comment: how can i check that? @CarlosGonzalez

Comment: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-character-set/ This is a tutorial about cahracter sets in mysql it may be helpful this may also help https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-syntax.html

Comment: i did `ALTER TABLE Channels MODIFY name VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET utf8;` and i guess it worked